# Ldap getting disabled users

Tags: php, ldap

I'm using this piece of code

```
$filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))";
$attr = array("displayName", "samaccountname", "thumbnailPhoto", "displayName", "mail", "IPPhone","employeeid");
$result = ldap_search($link, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr);
$entries_full = ldap_get_entries($link, $result);
```

My objective is to get all users that are not a computer and are not disabled. But I'm struggling with the filters.

Answer (score 0):

Is `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))` working for you?

Comment: Nope. it brings 0 results

Comment: It's like this on my AD `CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOCAL`

Comment: Yeah, the AD here looks identical. Is this filter working for you with any LDAP explorer? I checked mine using LEX (http://www.ldapexplorer.com/), the trial version is enough to check the filters.

However, your filter isn't returning anything with LEX.

Comment: Stupid me, your filter was working as well. Are you getting any result with your filter? If you're getting any result using a LDAP browser, the issue might be related to anything else but not the filter itself.

Comment: My filter is working, but it gets some users that are disabled, not only the enable ones.